# Custom State Management not working Vue3 - TS

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Problem: I need to transfer information between two separate components. Between a main component and a another component. I have tried to create a reactive State Management as described by the Vue docs, but the value of the object is always the starting, and does not reflect changes made by the other components.

What I've tried:
**store.ts**

```
const valueOriginal = ref("defaultValue");
export const store = reactive({ value: valueOriginal });
```

**componentA.vue**:

```
import { store } from "./store";
...

...
console.log("mounted with store object value: ", this.store.value);
this.store.value = "Modified by componentA.vue";
console.log("Modified store object value: ", this.store.value);
```

`componentB` is navigated to after `componentA` has changed the store value...

**componentB.vue**:

```
import { store } from "./store";
...

...
console.log("mounted with store object value: ", this.store.value); // this is the default value still
```

Comment: Your code works in isolation. Please provide context or a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-8vxkfz?file=src/components/A.vue) to show a working example. I'm not quite sure how your full code looks. Your mistake could be the usage of `this` but I'm not sure if you are using the Composition API. You're definition of the store itself looks fine.

I do recommend using [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/) as a store management which is maintained by the Vue core team. Using stores like you currently do could lead to security vulnerabilities when used in combination with SSR ([More info](https://pinia.vuejs.org/introduction.html#why-should-i-use-pinia)).